# How to type Multiple lines in cell (B)

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

When I type multiple lines in a cell (A) in Excel it works fine.  but then I am unable to type from the first line in the adjoining cell. (B) ...  it starts from the bottom line..  How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Press this button to vertically align at the top of a cell:

[image]